# How to disable object reference when using @JsonIdentityInfo?

Tags: json, jackson

When I use `JsonIdentityInfo` , for example

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@dataSet")
```

The Jackson will replace object, which has appear to id , such as following.

```
{
  "@dataSet" : 1,
  "createdDate" : 1374039391476,
  "lastUpdated" : 1374039391476,
  "dataSetId" : 1,
  "dataSetVersions" : [ {
    "createdDate" : 1374039391486,
    "lastUpdated" : 1374039391486,
    "dataSetVersionId" : null,
    "dataSetVersionNumber" : 1,
    "startTime" : null,
    "endTime" : null,
    "dataSet" : 1 <------ 1 reference to "@dataSetId":1
}
```

I have also tryed  `@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)`

This annotation force  object replace to id, but I want to disable the replacement

Can I disable this function not replace with id .?

Comment: Please look in to https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-identity-info-annotation.html this page it will help you.

Comment: What would be the expected result? This mapping by ID is needed to connect the `dataSetVersion` back to the `dataSet`. When you deserialize this json again it will replace the ID by the actual object reference.